# Root of $f(z)=z^6+\cos(|z|^6)(1+5z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $$f(z)=z^6+\cos(|z|^6)(1+5z^2)$$ Prove that there is a complex $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)=0$.

Additionally prove that there exists a ball of radius large enough such that we have six zeros counting multiplicity.

Comment: That's not a polynomial.

Comment: Ok. Thomas Andrews

Comment: I don't think this is differential topology

Comment: HINT: Use Rouché's Theorem.

Comment: This is a problem in differential topology (Guillemin & Pollack, in fact). Use degree and homotopy.

Comment: Spenser $f(z)$ is not analytic

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, note that the function is equal to $1$ at $0,$ and on the imaginary axis it is equal to $-(\Im z)^6 + \cos(|z|^6) (1 - 5 (\Im z)^2),$ in other words, negative for large $\Im z,$ so there is a zero. In fact, since the function is *even*, there are two zeros. For the second question, note that if you change variables $u = z^2,$ you get a cubic leading term, so you need to find just three zeros of that, which would give you six zeros of the function you started with.